# CentOS 7 iptables output does match output of firewall-cmd

Tags: iptables, centos7, firewall-cmd

Output of `iptables -L -v -n` does not match `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones`.

Specifically, I'm looking for the forwarding rules I have in place for two virtual machines. They can be clearly seen with iptables.

```
[root@localhost ~]# iptables -S -v | grep 192.168
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -i br0 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -c 160 12160 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -o br0 -c 160 12160 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.100.0/24 -i br0 -o virbr1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -c 110 8360 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.100.0/24 -i virbr1 -o br0 -c 110 8360 -j ACCEPT
```

I cannot find this same info with `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones`.

```
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: br0
  sources: 
  services: ftp dhcpv6-client http ssh
  ports: 5901/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

The other zones have even less info but I can display them if you wish to see.

I should be able to view these rules with `firewall-cmd`, correct? Or am I wrong to believe this? Or am I simply using the wrong `firewall-cmd` command? I've read through the manual for firewall-cmd and I can't seem to find the correct command if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

They look like firewall rules added by libvirt. These are not visible or manageable through firewalld.